# What is the solution of this code?

Tags: java

```
class Swap{
  public static void main(String args[]){
      int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      System.out.println("\n***Before Swapping***");
      System.out.println("Number 1 : "+num1);
      System.out.println("Number 2 : "+num2);
      //Swap logic
      num1 = num1 + num2;
      num2 = num1 - num2;
      num1 = num1 - num2;
      System.out.println("\n***After Swapping***");
      System.out.println("Number 1 : "+num1);
      System.out.println("Number 2 : "+num2);
  }
}
```

what's wrong with code, it don't happening compilation.
Something I am mistaking but I don't know what.
Can you help me?

When I compiled it.
It gave.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
at Swap.main(Main.java:5)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.aide.ui.build.java.RunJavaActivity$1.run(SourceFile:108)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: This code compile just fine for me.

Comment: If it fails compilation, then there is a compiler error. Please share that.

Comment: It is giving some errors.

Comment: `"When I compiled it. It gave...."` No, this is not a compilation error, and this is one source of confusion about your question. This is a run-time exception, and there's a big difference between the two. Your code compiles just fine, but throws an exception when you run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main class's arguments are empty, you can move the entire swap function to a new method (In this case I created `swapNum` method) and call it from your main class, as follow:

```
public class Swap
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      String[] myStringArray = {"1","2"};
      swapNum(myStringArray);
  }

  public static void swapNum(String[] args){
     int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      System.out.println("\n***Before Swapping***");
      System.out.println("Number 1 : "+num1);
      System.out.println("Number 2 : "+num2);
      //Swap logic
      num1 = num1 + num2;
      num2 = num1 - num2;
      num1 = num1 - num2;
      System.out.println("\n***After Swapping***");
      System.out.println("Number 1 : "+num1);
      System.out.println("Number 2 : "+num2);
  }


}
```

And the result is:

```
***Before Swapping***
Number 1 : 1
Number 2 : 2

***After Swapping***
Number 1 : 2
Number 2 : 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the program with command line arguments, you must be running it without arguments. You can verify this by changing the first two lines of `main` like,

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt("2");
int num2 = Integer.parseInt("5");
```

and it runs (as far as I can tell) as intended. That's why you get the error

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>    at Swap.main(Main.java:5)

#### tl;dr

Line 5 is `Integer.parseInt(args[0]);` and `args` is empty.

I would add runtime error handling for that with something like

```
if (args.length < 2) {
    System.err.println("Please provide two command line arguments");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

to provide a meaningful message in that case.